# GROUP BY error with TOP in T-SQL / SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table in my SQL Server database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CODIFICHE_FARMACI]
(
    [Principio_Attivo] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [LanguageID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Codice] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Confezione_rif] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [ATC] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Farmaco] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Confezione] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [Ditta] [nvarchar](100) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CODIFICHE_FARMACI] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LanguageID] ASC, [Codice] ASC)
)
```

Now I want extract from this table the first 60 record group by `Farmaco` column.

So I wrote this query :

```
SELECT TOP 60 * 
FROM CODIFICHE_FARMACI 
GROUP BY Farmaco
```

But I have this strange error:

> La colonna 'CODIFICHE_FARMACI.Principio_Attivo' non è valida nell'elenco di selezione perché non è inclusa né in una funzione di aggregazione né nella clausola GROUP BY.

In English:

> The column 'CODIFICHE_FARMACI.Principio_Attivo' is invalid in the select list because it is not included in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

**EDIT**: with this query, I get this result

[image]

As you can see I have replicate the column Farmaco (There are two times ABBA, ABESART)

> EDIT as result I want :

```
|FARMACO|
ABBA
ABESART
ABILIFY
```

Comment: Can you show us sample input and output?

Comment: All of your columns are nvarchar. Group by some field means that you want to receive distinct values of this field and some aggregate value for other fields (sum, avg, min, max). What aggregate value do you want to receive of nvarchar fields?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to select the first 60 `Farmaco` values while showing only distinct values, you can try using `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 60 Farmaco 
FROM [dbo].[CODIFICHE_FARMACI]
ORDER BY Farmaco
```

Note that if you really have records that are duplicate then it implies your data is not normalized.  Possibly, the duplicates only are the same with regard to certain columns, but not others.

Comment: Show us what output you actually want.  Note that those pairs of records are not the same in all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Top 60
  a.Farmaco
  FROM [dbo].[CODIFICHE_FARMACI] A
GROUP BY A.Farmaco
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 60 cf.Farmaco
FROM CODIFICHE_FARMACI AS cf
GROUP BY cf.Farmaco
ORDER BY cf.Farmaco
```

When you use GROUP BY, you'll get a distinct values from the column/s followed by GROUP BY (in your case Farmaco).

First the FROM statement is going be executed, then the retrieved data set now with alias cf from CODIFICHE_FARMACI is going to be grouped by cf.Farmaco.

The SELECT command will retrieve only cf.Farmaco column values, with ORDER BY they will be ordered ascending (because ORDER BY expression, has a default ascending ordering). At the end TOP 60 will filter only 60 ROWS from the data set.

When you specify SELECT * and you have GROUP BY clause you will have a problem, because every column written in GROUP BY must be at the SELECT statement.

You can also add columns that are a result of aggregate functions such as SUM, MIN, MAX and etc. to the SELECT statement.

Comment: Please use the \` sign to mark `inline code` elements to make your code even more readable. Thank you!